# can DDL control Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Can A DropdownList control Checkboxes, Basically what i Mean is

I have a bunch of checkboxes that represent Names settings. All checkBoxes Are displayed on the page.

I created a DDL with  names, If I select a name from the DDL can I have that DDL check whatever setting assigned to that name.

or that is not a built in Functionality of DDL. any ideas

```
       `var r = document.getElementById("Search$AllNamesDDL").innerHTML;
        var User = e.option[e.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log('User:' + User);
        var rs = r.split('</option>');

        document.getElementById("Search$AllNamesDDL").innerHTML;
        for (var i =0; i<=rs ,i++)
        {
            If (rs[i])
            {
                var cleanme = rs[i].replace('<option value="', "");

                var sub0 = cleanme.split('">');

                console.log("sub0 for (" + i + ") =>" + sub0[1]);

                if (sub0[1]) 
                {
                    var startWith = sub0[1].substring(0, 1);

                    console.log('The letter you asked for was found for this object');

                    document.getElementById("Search$AllDevicesDDL").innerHTML += '<option id="' + sub0[1] + '" value="' + sub0[1] + '">' + sub0[1] + '</option>';

                }//ifstarWith=alpha


            }//for the if(rs[i]

        }//for the for condirtional

        strSelected='';
        var e=document.getElementById("Search_settingSelectCheckBox");

        var strSelected=e.options[e.SelectedIndex].value;


        $('Search_settingSelectCheckBox').change(function() {
            var selected = $('Search_settingSelectCheckBox option:selected');
            if (selected.val() == "Select A Device") {
                $('input[input=".markerSettingSelectCheckBoxList"]').prop('checked', false);
            }
            else {
                $('input[input=".markerSettingSelectCheckBoxList"]').prop('checked', true);
            }
        })`








    }//for the whole function
    )`
```

here is the asp code:
`

```
             EnableViewState="true"  >
            <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="Select"  Enabled="true"/> 
        </asp:DropDownList>

         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllNamesSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Names]">
```

```
<input type="button" value="Select All" class="markerSelectAll"/>
<input type="button" value="Unselect All" class="markerUnSelectAll"/>

<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="SettingsObjectDataSource" SelectMethod="GetDistinctNamesSettingNames" 
    TypeName="class"></asp:ObjectDataSource>`
```

Comment: why don't you post some of your markup and code that you've tried?

Comment: The answer is yes.  Yet, you are move likely to receive help if you post the markup and code that you have tried.

Comment: I just posted the code up top any ideas, or a sequence of steps on how to do it, Mt though is how to invoke unique settings Names by selected names. I hope I am Making sense

Comment: In order to help you let me understand how can i bind a "dropdown selection" to a "checkbox checked", for example a selected value "Green" how is going to search over the checkbox collection and search for example "light green" "dark green" "plain green" "green fruit", if you give us a example of real values maybe we can work it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what I mean I have a list of Equipment, Each of these Equipment is assigned certain settings.  Some equipment have common settings, but in The DB each piece of Equipment is assigned its own settings. All settings are represented by checkBoxes, The reason for the check boxes being there is, when Checked the are searchable and also the search results can be exported to A CSV file, so A drop Down List with Equipment’s name will help Auto Checking the right settings for the Selected Device. Instead of manually checking the checkboxes for the device that needs to be searched